# Node.js version always 16.x macos

Tags: node.js, nvm

I initially installed node with the latest version available at the time, `v16.14.2` (this was installed using brew). I then started to need version `v14.20.0`, so I installed nvm.

I managed to install version 14.20.0 using nvm and to use it, but whenever I open a new terminal instance, it still uses 16.14.2. I did use `nvm use 14` & `nvm alias default 14.20.0`.

The issue here is that I tried to use `nvm uninstall 16.14.2` which says that version is not installed. I also tried to manually remove that version, but there is no version 16 folder inside `ls ~/.nvm/versions/node`. I also tried uninstalling node with brew, no errors there, but the default version is somehow still 16.14.2.

LE: not sure if it's helping, but I am using an m1 mac

Comment: What does `which node` say?

Comment: @robertklep `/usr/local/bin/node`

Comment: Could be that it was installed with the official Node.js installer (from https://nodejs.org). If you really want nvm to manage your Node.js versions, remove it from `/usr/local/bin`.